# Handontable not showing more than 5 columns

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I used **colHeaders** property to set headers.
but only first five are visible until I paste data of more than 5 columns
code:

```
 var dataPrePop =["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
 var container = document.getElementById('example');
 var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    colHeaders: dataPrePop,  
    contextMenu: true 
 });
```

Full source code -

```js
var dataPrePop = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

var container = document.getElementById('example');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  colHeaders: dataPrePop,
  //minSpareCols: 1,
  //minSpareRows: 1,
  //rowHeaders: true,
  //colHeaders: true,
  contextMenu: true
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial;
}

a {
  color: #34A9DC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<h2>Handsontable Basic Example (100x10)</h2>
<p>
  Head to <a href="https://handsontable.com" target="_blank">handsontable.com</a> to learn more about Handsontable.
</p>

<div id="example"></div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6t768pq/962/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work for you -

if you want you can set **`minCols`**

```
 minCols: 8 // -- this will do your job
```

am creating a working sample for you.

```js
var dataPrePop = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

var container = document.getElementById('example');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  colHeaders: dataPrePop,
  minCols: 8,
  //minSpareCols: 1,
  //minSpareRows: 1,
  //rowHeaders: true,
  //colHeaders: true,
  contextMenu: true
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial;
}

a {
  color: #34A9DC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<h2>Handsontable Basic Example (100x10)</h2>
<p>
  Head to <a href="https://handsontable.com" target="_blank">handsontable.com</a> to learn more about Handsontable.
</p>

<div id="example"></div>
```

**#2 way should be using `data`**

In the below sample `createSpreadsheetData(5, 8)` *handles the number of column and row in the table.*

```js
var dataPrePop = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(5, 8);

var container = document.getElementById('example');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: dataPrePop,
  //minSpareCols: 1,
  //minSpareRows: 1,
  //rowHeaders: true,
  //colHeaders: true,
  contextMenu: true
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial;
}

a {
  color: #34A9DC;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0 20px;
}

h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.4/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<h2>Handsontable Basic Example (100x10)</h2>
<p>
  Head to <a href="https://handsontable.com" target="_blank">handsontable.com</a> to learn more about Handsontable.
</p>

<div id="example"></div>
```

I hope this was helpful to you.